# Could you explain why the expected running time of randomized quick sort is Theta of nlogn?

Tags: quicksort

What is difference between expected running time and running time AND Could you explain why the expected running time of randomized quick sort is Theta of nlogn.

Answer (score 1):

Expected Running Time:
For often times expected running time just means the average running time for random inputs. But if it's about a randomized algorithm, which is the case here, it means that the algorithm is running inputs with random choices made by the algorithm.

Proofing running time:
As for proofing the theta n(logn) running time of quicksort, it will be involved with more complicated mathematics, here's reference from CMU that proofs the running time of theta n(logn)(https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f11/lectures/lect0906.pdf).

Not to bother with intricate mathematics, I am only going to focus on how we can comprehend this running time by intuition

Non-random Inputs:If each pivot has rank somewhere in the middle 50 percent, that is, between the 25th percentile and the 75th percentile, then it splits the elements with at least 25% and at most 75% on each side. Then splitting up the data gives us O(logn) and calling on each of them gives us total running time theta of nlog(n). Make sure you understand why this non-randomized quicksort has average running time theta of nlog(n).

Now let's talk about expected running time of randomized quicksort...

When inputs are random, the pivot is not guarateed to be in the middle 50 percent. However, when we start from a random pivot, the pivot would land in the middle 50 percent for about half of the time. Imagine that you are flipping a coin coin until you get n heads. On average cases, you will only need to flip 2k times. By the same token, Quicksort's recursion will terminate on expected 2 times of what non-random inputs would need, which should only be constant multiple of O(logn). Each level of call tree would be called on n times, the expected total work will still be theta (nlogn).